# Angular - ng2-smar-table Add custom button and action

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am trying to add or change the style of the button in ng2-smart-table, but the button style is not changing. For an instance i provided the link below where i want to change the "Edit", "Delete", "Cancel" and "Add New" to some button style (may be font-awesome or bootstrap button).

I tried to change the code in the below explained way, but still this does not resolve the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52086092/add-custom-action-button-ng2-smart-table

Sample Application :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-smart-table-global-search

https://ng2-smart-table-global-search.stackblitz.io/

As well, when i try to edit the row values, text box size for first four cells are proper, but when it comes to other cells (from 5th) it is very small. want to keep proper text box size for that too.

Answer (score 0):

I found the below way it is working.

```
settings = {
    pager: {
      display: true,
      perPage: 8
    },
   delete: {
      deleteButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg">Delete</i>',
      confirmDelete: true
    },
    add: {
      addButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg">Add</i>',
      createButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-lg">Create</i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-times fa-lg">Cancel</i>',
    },
    edit: {
      editButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true">Edit</i>',
      saveButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-check fa-lg">Save</i>',
      cancelButtonContent: '<i class="fa fa-times fa-lg">Cancel</i>',
    },
columns: {
.....
.....
}
}
```